# Difference Between Opening Jupyter Notebooks on Anaconda or the Terminal

Tags: anaconda

I'm pretty new at this so thanks for the patience. I was trying to import some libraries like matplotlib into a Jupiter Notebook file and I would get an error claiming that "there is not module named matplotlib". After having a difficult time installing it through the terminal (every time I used 'pip install matplotlib' the command would terminate due to some error), I tried opening the notebook file through the Anaconda navigator (opening the anaconda navigator, clicking on the Jupyter Notebook, which is slower and less convenient). However, importing actually worked with this method. It was the exact same file. The only variation was the way I opened Jupyter Notebook.

My question is why does this happen? What is going on that I don't know? It seems like an important piece of information to understanding how file systems work but I can't figure it out. Also, how can I fix this?

Comment: Which OS are you working on?

Comment: macOS Catalina @Lakshmi-Intel

Comment: Ifyou are working with anaconda install the packages directly through conda repositories, with commands like: